# Birational schemes admitting finite etale maps of same degree are isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recently I came across the following question:

Let $X$, $Y$ be smooth schemes such that they both admit a finite etale morphism of the same degree to a scheme $S$. Furthermore, there is a birational map $f$ between $X$ and $Y$. Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic?

What I tried so far is take the closure of the graph of $f$, denoted by $\overline{Γ_f}\subseteq X\times_S Y$. In that way I obtain two morphisms $\overline{Γ_f}\to X$ and $\overline{Γ_f}\to Y$ and I have shown that these are birational morphisms which I would like to show that they are isomorphisms to obtain the desired result.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your notation suggests that $f$ is compatible with the morphisms onto $S$, correct? (Otherwise, how's the graph contained in the fibre-product over $S$?)

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Any assumptions on $S$? I think I have counter-examples if $S$ is reducible and I have an argument in mind if $S$ is integral (and perhaps some more niceness-assumptions...)